# Android draw part of a bitmap to a Canvas without creating a new Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop, porter-duff

I have got a `Canvas`. Its associated `Bitmap` is some image (*see 1st image*).

On top of that (*see 4th image*), I want to draw a part (*see 3rd image*) of a `Bitmap` (*see 2nd image*).

[image: First image (sea)]
[image: Second image (island texture)]
[image: Third image (cut island)]
[image: Fourth image (island on sea)]

Now, I could create a cropped version of the bitmap. But that would require me to copy the entire `Bitmap` (which I would need to do many times each frame).

From what I have seen, `PorterDuff` doesn't really help either as using a pattern-`Bitmap` to cut the unwanted pixels after drawing would remove the original image below.

Is there any efficient way of "*telling android what pixels of the bitmap to draw*"? I am thinking of something like an implementation of an `interface` that takes an x- and y- coordinate and returns a boolean of whether to paint the according pixel.

Comment: `which I would need to do many times each frame` not clear if you are building a 2D game or some animation used with Android views. If the 'water' and 'trees' are static, then porter-duff should work with an 'island' mask.

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang! Yes, it's a 2D game. The water was just an example. The image below is self drawn / the canvas from onDraw(). So I can't just draw in reverse order. I need something to pass the bitmap and the mask at the same time, to always ask the mask if a certain pixel of the bitmap should be drawn.

Comment: Without seeing code, multiple passes with porter-duff sounds like what you want but are trying to avoid. Off-topic: if you are doing a 2D game, I would use one of the existing 2D game engines as they use OpenGL ES based engines. If you are writing your own engine these old videos: [Google I/O - Writing Real-Time Games for Android](https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic) and [Google I/O - Writing real-time games for Android redux](https://youtu.be/7-62tRHLcHk) which provides good info. Canvas drawing uses and is limited by: [Drawn out: How Android renders (Google IO 2018)](https://youtu.be/zdQRIYOST64)